# How to fix "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time"?

Tags: swift

Absolute rookie here, stumbling my way through trial and error. I have come across a problem I cannot solve, despite searching here for hours, and trying many different ideas. The error I am receiving is (`TotalFuelLoad.text` line):

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

The code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var LeftMainTankQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var RightMainTankQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AuxTankQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TailTankQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TotalFuelLoad: UILabel!

    @IBAction func TankFuelChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        let LeftMainTankQuantityValue = Int(LeftMainTankQuantity.text!)
        let RightMainTankQuantityValue = Int(RightMainTankQuantity.text!)
        let AuxTankQuantityValue = Int(AuxTankQuantity.text!)
        let TailTankQuantityValue = Int(TailTankQuantity.text!)

        TotalFuelLoad.text = String(describing: (LeftMainTankQuantityValue ?? 0) + (RightMainTankQuantityValue ?? 0) + (AuxTankQuantityValue ?? 0) + (TailTankQuantityValue ?? 0))
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: What about “breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions” ?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comment. I have tried breaking it up, trying to follow examples posted previously on here, but I could not get it to work. Sorry, absolute rookie here

Comment: Moving the `?? 0` up into the individual variable definitions is probably enough

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the suggestion I tried that but got the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_?'"

Comment: FYI - It is standard practice to name variables, functions, and enum cases to start with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters. So you should fix the names of all of your variables and your function.

Comment: Hi maddy, thanks for that. Understood, I will go through and amend now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this in 3 stages:

1. Use `??` twice to safely unwrap and convert your values to `Int`.
2. Add your values up to create `total`.
3. Use string interpolation to convert `total` to `String`.

---

```
@IBAction func TankFuelChanged(_ sender: Any) {

    let leftMainTankQuantityValue = Int(LeftMainTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let rightMainTankQuantityValue = Int(RightMainTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let auxTankQuantityValue = Int(AuxTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let tailTankQuantityValue = Int(TailTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0

    let total = leftMainTankQuantityValue + rightMainTankQuantityValue + auxTankQuantityValue + tailTankQuantityValue

    TotalFuelLoad.text = "\(total)"

}
```

Comment: Hi vacawama, brilliant! thank you so much. You just solved hours of frustration for me. I will now go through it line by line to understand how it works. Thank you again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @JackSparrow.  Please accept my answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left to turn it green.  That lets others know your problem has been solved and gives the answer and you a bit a rep.

Comment: Hi @vacawama, thanks for that. I knew there must have been a way to confirm the answer and give rep. Thanks again for your help solving this.

Comment: Hi @vacawama, sorry to bother again, I have one more question regarding this. It currently works well, adding up the 4 values, but only does so when input is finished. That is, I have to select another text field before it totals the values. Is there a way to update the total as I type? (I don't have to select another box for it to update)